# How to I randomise the interval for my game

Tags: javascript, html

Wassup, I'm trying to create an HTML game but can't figure out one bit of code. I want to randomise the interval of the obstacles constantly so there is no pattern after a few frames.

```
function updateGameArea() {
var x, y, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h;
for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
        myGameArea.stop();
        return;
    } 
 }
 myGameArea.clear();
 myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
 if (myGameArea.frameNo == 1 || everyinterval(600)) {
    x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
    y = myGameArea.canvas.height - 350;

    a = myGameArea.canvas.width - -4444;
    b = myGameArea.canvas.height - 750;

    c = myGameArea.canvas.width - -20674;
    d = myGameArea.canvas.height - 750;

    e = myGameArea.canvas.width - -11111;
    f = myGameArea.canvas.height - 1150;

    g = myGameArea.canvas.width - -40678;
    h = myGameArea.canvas.height - 1150;

    myObstacles.push(new component(500, 300, "green", x, y));

    myObstacles.push(new component(500, 300, "green", a, b));

    myObstacles.push(new component(500, 300, "green", c, d));

    myObstacles.push(new component(500, 300, "green", e, f));

    myObstacles.push(new component(500, 300, "green", g, h));
  }
  for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    myObstacles[i].x += -5;
    myObstacles[i].a += -1;
    myObstacles[i].c += -1;
    myObstacles[i].e += -1;
    myObstacles[i].g += -1;
    myObstacles[i].update();
  }
  myScore.text="SCORE: " + myGameArea.frameNo;
  myScore.update();
  myGamePiece.newPos();    
  myGamePiece.update();
 }

function everyinterval(n) {
if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 == 0) {return true;}
return false;
}
```

Here is what I have so far. PLEASE HELP!!!`enter code here`

Comment: `Math.random()` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Math.random()`. This is from MDN:

> This example returns a random number between the specified values. The
>   returned value is no lower than (and may possibly equal) min, and is
>   less than (and not equal) max.
>
> ```
> function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
>   return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
> }
> ```

Comment: where do you want to access random numbers !?

Comment: well I want the obstacles to have random intervals, at the moment I have 5 obstacles but ideally I just want three that have random intervals as to make the game not so easy. does that math.random() fit into the code I have shown?? :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use two functions, one for the update/action and one for calling the timeout with a randome value.

With a more advanced style, you could add a check if the next call of timeout should stop.

```js
function randomTimeout(fn) {
    var t = Math.floor(Math.random() *  4 + 2) * 1000;
    console.log('randomTimeout', t);
    setTimeout(fn, t);
}

function update() {
    console.log('update');
    randomTimeout(update);
}

update();
```

Comment: the `update` function is the equivalent to your `updateGameArea` function. (but i do not get the part of you interval handling.)